# VM-Ware Virtual Disk recognized as /dev/sd[a-p] in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, virtualization, disk

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is installed on an ESXi at home. The disk is `sda sda1 sda2`. However, another Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS installed on Tencent Cloud(possiblily Xen) shows the disk as `vda vda1`.

I know that usually vd means virtual disk. But why the Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't realize it's using a virtual disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vd* - usually resembles virualization aware para-virt drivers.
sd* - provides a SCSI API to the kernel (could be virtio still by e.g. virtio-scsi)

This was answered many times, like [here on stackexchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/803388/what-is-the-difference-between-dev-vda-and-dev-sda)

In your case of ESXi it just means that the disk setup it provides by default considers the disk a normal disk driver not being virtualization aware - maybe similar to the virtio-scsi example above.

The kernel starts with [major/minor numbers to names](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) followed by  advanced rules how to name devices via udev `/lib/udev/rules.d/*`.
If needed you can extend the latter to get a different result.